# Как удалить значение из поля с помощью Java Reflection

Tags: java, рефлексия

При попыткt установить в поле значение `null` я получаю ошибку

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field MyObject.status
>   has type int, got null

```
field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(object, null);
```

Это происходить скорее всего из за того что поле примитивного типа.

Вопрос, как можно установить значение поля типа `int` значение `null`?

Comment: Никак. int - это примитивный тип и не может иметь значение null. by design.

Comment: да, но до момента пока я не установил в это поле значение в первый раз оно будет возвращать мне null.

Comment: Нет не будет. Все int поля инициализируются значением `0`.

Comment: покажите как вы берете значение из поля

Comment: @Nofate так да, я почему то думал что там null будет.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman myObject.getStatus();  Достаю значение как и обычно  через геттер, а вот устанавливаю с помощью  рефлексии

Comment: и этот код возвращает вам null?

Comment: нет,  он возвращает 0

Comment: очень похоже, что у вас XY проблема. попробуйте описать задачу, а не решение.

Comment: Я описал проблему а не решение, и решение уже по-ходу найдено, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Это то же самое что и пытаться написать что-то типа:

```
int i=null;
```

компилятор предсказуемо скажет, что это ошибка, то же самое вам пытается сказать *Java Reflection API*

Comment: Это я понимаю, но есть ли способ сделать так что бы при обращении к гетеру этого поля мне возвращало null, может каким то образом можно не присваивать значение , а наоборот -  удалить значение из поля?

Comment: @KirillStoianov Зачем вам `null`? Если уж сильно хочется сделайте тип `Integer` вместо `int`

Comment: @Nofate да, наверное, так и сделаю